# Absolutely positioned element going off screen when filled

Tags: html, css, css-position

I have a DIV container, `.floatingPage`, which is positioned absolutely over two other DIV containers `.top` and `.bottom`. My problem is that the contents of the `.floatingPage` element are dynamic and *sometimes* contain a lot of data, which extends `.floatingPage` below the visible part of the screen.

```css
.top { 
  height:350px; 
  background:'images/background.png'; 
  position:relative; 
}

.bottom { 
  height:350px; 
  background:#F1F1F1; 
}

.floatingPage { 
  position:absolute; 
  top:50px; 
}
```

```html
<div class="top">
    <div class="floatingPage">
        // blah blah blah (lots of data)
    </div>
</div>
```

Now, because I know my app's users use JS (company control panel), I have been calculating the height of the `.floatingPage` element and extending the height of `.bottom` to suit the new contents. This has been OK until now and has started to cause problems. Plus, I don't want to do this hack for other projects that have users without JS.

I need this `floatingPage` element to float over the top of the other two - that's the whole point of site's design. How can I keep this affect but prevent it from running off the page, without JS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```css
.top { 
  height:350px; 
  background:'images/background.png'; 
  position:relative; 
}

.bottom { 
  height:350px; 
  background:#F1F1F1; 
}

.floatingPage { 
  position:absolute; 
  top      : 50px; 
  bottom   : 50px;
  overflow : auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="top">
    <div class="floatingPage">
        // blah blah blah (lots of data)
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: the trick for me was explicitly giving a value to `bottom` - thanks

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried absolute positioning specifying the bottom, rather than the top for the .floatingPage element?

eg:

```
.floatingPage { position:absolute; bottom:10px; }
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using the overflow attribute and setting the height of the DIV?

Answer (score 0):

If you need the element to float over the top of the other two, try adding a z-index and use overflow.

here's a jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/k8w79/